# creating a function to subset data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function in R to subset data based on ID in a data frame like below, but the function I wrote does not work and it doesn't give me an error message either. Can someone let me know how to fix my function code?

```
subset1<-function(id){df2<-df[df$ID==id,]}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUGDY.png)

Comment: Do you need to write your own function? Else, if you want to filter rows, use `dplyr::filter(df, ID == id)`, or use `dplyr::select` to select columns,

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Very informative!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `[[` inside a function

```
f1 <- function(id){
      df[df[["ID"]] == id,]
    }
f1(11)
#  ID Item
#1 11    a
```

Comment: Ohh! Thanks for such a quick response..! This works perfectly!